# SQL Create table in database ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I would like to create a database with a couple tables in it. I am using SSMS and it is easy enough to accomplish said task by right-click creating, but I would like to use query/command line (not sure how to phrase that).

Create a database and table

```
    CREATE DATABASE test_employees;

    CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeesBasicInfo
    (
        MyKeyField VarChar(8) PRIMARY KEY,
        FirstName VarChar(30) NOT NULL,
        LastName VarChar(50) NOT NULL,
        DateStarted DateTime NOT NULL,
        Age Int NOT NULL,
        ModifiedDate DateTime NULL
    );
```

But I have no idea where the table goes or how to move/link it to database test_employees.

Also, if you feel ambition in answering my question then the next step is to auto-generate data for all fields. Any links you could provide would be helpful. And, if anything I'm doing is not best-practice please let me know - I'm just getting into SQL.

Comment: Making things more difficult than necessary is not what I would call a best practice.  Regarding, generating data automatically, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Something else that is not a good practice is to store a person's age.  It changes over time.

Comment: haha, I understand what you mean about making things more difficult. I find that is the best way to learn though.

Comment: @DanBracuk Well my end goal is using an interface that reads data from a SQL database, so I would like to create a couple basic tables with approx. 100 entries that I can query. So, I want to randomly generate names (if possible), ages, and datestarted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've created the database you need to

```
Use test_employees
Go
```

This sets your current working database for subsequent statements.

Alternatively you can qualify your create table with the database name

```
Create Table test_employees.dbo.EmployeesBasicInfo (
    MyKeyField varchar(8) primary key,
    FirstName varchar(30) not null,
    LastName varchar(50) not null,
    DateStarted DateTime not null,
    Age int not null,
    ModifiedDate datetime null
);
```

You've probably created this table in your default database, which may well be `master`.

Also for any recent version of SQL Server, consider using `datetime2` instead of `datetime` (or `date` if you don't need the time component). It's better in all respects.

Comment: Awesome! I swear that answer was not easy to find. I searched for a while and couldn't find it.

Comment: Might be good to place a "go" command between the create database and create table (probably best before the USE).

Comment: @RussellSchutte I've put it in, and I know a lot of the auto-generated scripts do this, but I've never figured out exactly why.

Comment: As I understand it, Laurence, the "go" is purely an SSMS command, telling SSMS to wait until the last command has returned its status/finished before continuing with the next command.  Without the GO, I think it's possible that you request the database to be created and then go ahead and try to USE it before it's done being created.

Comment: @RussellSchutte So should you put a GO statement after every CREATE statement if you the subsequent command uses that newly created "something"?

Comment: I think that's advised.  Maybe someone with more knowledge can answer with more certainty, but I think so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to create a table 1st and then you can add some test data into it to practice with .......

TO CREATE A TABLE :

```
Create Table dbo.BasicInfo (
    MyKeyField INT primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(30) not null,
    LastName varchar(50) not null,
    DateStarted DateTime not null,
    Age int not null,
    ModifiedDate datetime null
)
GO
```

TO ADD PRACTICE DATA:

```
DECLARE @Value INT = 1

WHILE @Value <= 100
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO dbo.BasicInfo (FirstName, LastName, DateStarted, Age, ModifiedDate)
        VALUES           ('First_Name_' + CAST(@Value AS VARCHAR), 'Last_Name_'+ CAST(@Value AS VARCHAR), DATEADD(DAY, -CONVERT(INT, (5000+1)*RAND()), GETDATE()),
                     18 + CONVERT(INT, (30-10+1)*RAND()),  DATEADD(DAY,  10 + (30-10)*RAND() ,DATEADD(DAY, -CONVERT(INT, (5000+1)*RAND()), GETDATE()))) 
        SET @Value = @Value + 1
    END
```

if you want to add more then 100 rows in your table just replace the number or rows you wish to add to your table with 100 in this code